# getting error when trying to table->json('options') in migration

Tags: laravel, mariadb

My migration looks like this

```
    Schema::create('reports', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigincrements('id');
        $table->json('options');
    });
```

I get this error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>
> check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'json not null) default character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci' at line 1

If I remove `$table->json('options');` there are no errors.

Laravel 5.3 documentation mentions this https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/migrations so I am not doing anything wrong, any ideas why I am getting this error?

I am using MariaDB version 10.1.16 which has support for json type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MariaDB supports JSON in two ways, neither of which is a "datatype".  The error was not caught by Laravel (`$table->json(...)`) because other databases do have a JSON *datatype*.

- [*Json table type*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/connect-json-table-type/) (10.0.16) talks about how to use "Connect" to hook a Json-encoded file into MariaDB.
- [*Dynamic Columns*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/dynamic-columns/) (10.0.1) employs a `BLOB` under the covers, plus a function `COLUMN_JSON` to interpret the column as Json.

Whether MariaDB picks up [*Oracle 5.7's JSON datatype*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html) (5.7.8) is a matter of speculation.

Answer (score 1):

I've looked around for the solution for this.

Assuming that your MariaDB version is correct, it does appear that it doesn't support it. I did find a closed GitHub issues on the laravel repo, to which [this comment](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/13622#issuecomment-221567026) states

```
MariaDB 10.2 supported JSON. (Alpha version. Not recommended by Maria to production server. 
Only testing.)

MariaDB 10.1 do not support JSON (
```

So I would suggest that either your MariaDB version is wrong, or does in fact, not support the JSON column.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your db does not support JSON

You can make a text and save your json file as strings and then parse them when retrieve from database.